# How can i delete particular item stored inside local storage?

Tags: javascript, local-storage

Values stored inside local storage

```
{"10":true,"11":true,"16":false}
```

I want to delete a particular data stored inside local storage e.g. 10

```
var checkboxValues = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem('checkboxValues')) || {};

$.each(checkboxValues, function(key, value) {
                if(value===true) {
                    delete checkboxValues[key];
                    }
                }
            });
```

I stored all checkboxes id and value during onload, and want to remove those checkboxes id with true value when user submit the form.

With the method used above, I unable to delete the data. Is anything wrong with my code?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In order to delete an item from localStorage you have to use `removeItem()` function but in your case you actually need to update it. So first so you have to overwrite the existing value. See the code below. Here is a [Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/f37d29ef/)

```js
//set the value for first time suppose
localStorage.setItem("checkboxValues", JSON.stringify({
  "10": true,
  "11": true,
  "16": false
}));
   //get the value and update
var checkboxValues = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem('checkboxValues')) || {};
$.each(checkboxValues, function(key, value) {
  if (value === true) {
    delete checkboxValues[key];
  }
})
   //store the updated value back to localStorage
localStorage.setItem("checkboxValues", JSON.stringify(checkboxValues));
console.log(JSON.stringify(checkboxValues));//logs {"16":false}
console.log(JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem('checkboxValues')));
// logs an object with only one property {16:false}
```

Answer (score 0):

before saving json object into the localstorage please convert the json object into string and then store it in localstorage like this

```
JSON.stringify({"10":true,"11":true,"16":false});
```

and then where you are parsing things it works correctly, just on saving please convert json object into string
here is the updated code

```
var jsonData = JSON.stringify({"10":true,"11":true,"16":false});
localStorage.setItem('checkboxValues', jsonData);

var checkboxValues = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem('checkboxValues')) || {};

$.each(checkboxValues, function(key, value) {
    if(value===true) {
        delete checkboxValues[key];
    }
});
```

here it is showing it working fine
https://iamlalit.tinytake.com/sf/MTc1ODUwMl81Nzc4NzMw

Comment: Yes, i did. But it wont delete the particular data.

Comment: Strange just copy paste the above code as I did in my screenshot in your chrome console and see the output

Comment: I am missing update local storage statement after delete the data. Thanks for help.